# Blazored (async void function) - program jumping out of function before creating directory

Tags: c#, async-await, task, blazor

I have a problem with an async function in my web-UI which is kind of hard to resolve.

I use a login-function for my program, where the login/session data is handled within the
`myLocalStore-Object`.

This object is initialized / "injected" at the start of the login-page:

```
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService myLocalStore
```

Next, i have my login-function which does two things:

1. Create directory for user-related data (images, .csv files etc.)
2. Save Session-related data (User name, Session Path, ExpertMode etc..)

Now, i want to create my directory first, and save the session data aftewards:

```cs
public async void SaveSession()
{
    ClearSession();
    
    Message = "Session Saved";
    
    string SessionPathRel = "_" + Login.Name + "/";
    
    string SessionPathAbs = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    SessionPathAbs = SessionPathAbs + @"\wwwroot\" + "_" + Login.Name + @"\";
    
    //CREATE DIRECTORY
    Directory.CreateDirectory(SessionPathAbs);
    
    //SAVE SESSION DATA
    await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("UserLoginName", Login.Name);        
    await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("SessionPathAbs", SessionPathAbs);
    await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("SessionPathRel", SessionPathRel); 
    await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("isLogged", true);
```

The problem now is that the program is running, it skips / jumps over the "Directory.CreateDirectory" line and finishes the function **without** a directory being created. When i use a breakpoint at the relating line,  everything is running correctly.

We made some attempts already (using sync instead of async functions, returning Task<Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService> instead of void for SaveSession) , but it all did not work out. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

EDIT:

fixed it with use of the `Task.Run()` - command. Just paste the code as an example here:

```cs
    public async Task SaveSession()
    {
        await ClearSession();
    
        Message = "Session Saved";
    
        string SessionPathRel = "_" + Login.Name + "/";
    
        string SessionPathAbs = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        SessionPathAbs = SessionPathAbs + @"\wwwroot\" + "_" + Login.Name + @"\";
    
        //CREATE DIRECTORY
        await Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(SessionPathAbs));
    
        //SAVE SESSION DATA
        await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("UserLoginName",    Login.Name);        
        await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("SessionPathAbs",   SessionPathAbs);
        await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("SessionPathRel",   SessionPathRel); 
        await myLocalStore.SetItemAsync("isLogged",         true);
        //GlobalConfiguration.URL_Handler.updateURLWithSubname(Login.Name);
    
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(URL_Handler.DashboardURL, true);
    }
    
    public async Task ClearSession()
    {
    try{
       string SessionPathAbs   = await myLocalStore.GetItemAsync<string>("SessionPathAbs");
       System.IO.DirectoryInfo SessionDirectoryAbs = new DirectoryInfo(SessionPathAbs);
    
       await Task.Run(() => SessionDirectoryAbs.Delete(true));
            //SessionDirectoryAbs.Delete(true);
     }
     catch
     {
         
     }
    
     GlobalConfiguration.URL_Handler.clearURLWithSubname();
    
     Message = "Session is clear";
     SessionValue = "";
    
     await myLocalStore.ClearAsync();
    
 }
```

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It's intended for event handlers. Use `async Task` instead.

Comment: Tried it, but i think there is another problem, which is: I additionally have a ClearSession()- Function, which gets called "before" save session but actually gets executed afterwards. So, the program created the directory, and clears the directory afterwards even though ClearSession() gets called previously. (Guess it's some problem with organizing order of execution for async-methods. Is there any way i can "force" clear session to be executed even though the method is "Async Task" ?

Comment: Who is calling `SaveSession`, and where is it being called?    Web Assembly or Server?   `Directory.CreateDirectory` isn't going to work on the browser as you have no access to the local file system.

Comment: Agree with MrC - but also, you haven't "fixed it" you've just swallowed the error. Also, I don't think you want to store the information in the browser like that - really bad idea to store the username and a path to what is potentially a directory on the server like that. It wouldn't be hard for someone to change username in their browser storage and potentially read or Clear another user's session data

Comment: thx for the feedback, well i don't have so much experience with developing web-UIs. do you have a solid link to how to implement it cleanly? I am using blazor server.

Comment: "I am using blazor server" - then don't store the data in \wwwroot, it is the least safe location. Make a data folder.